# Rails, Mongoid, and Devise nested Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I am trying to Nest a class within Devise that will hold a user's skills and desired skills into an array but I can not seem to get my form objects to save into the array.

```
    Class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

 ## Database authenticatable
 field :email,              :type => String, :null => false, :default => ""
 field :encrypted_password, :type => String, :null => false, :default => ""



 ## Recoverable
 field :reset_password_token,   :type => String
 field :reset_password_sent_at, :type => Time

 ## Rememberable
 field :remember_created_at, :type => Time

 ## Trackable
 field :sign_in_count,      :type => Integer, :default => 0
 field :current_sign_in_at, :type => Time
 field :last_sign_in_at,    :type => Time
 field :current_sign_in_ip, :type => String
 field :last_sign_in_ip,    :type => String


 field :first_name
 field :last_name

 field :location


 index([[:skills, :desired]], :background => true)

 validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name,  :location
 validates_uniqueness_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :case_sensitive => false
 attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,     :remember_me,  :location

embeds_one :skills
end
 class Skills
 include Mongoid::Document

 field :skills, type => String
 field :desired, type => String

 embedded_in :user 
 end
```

How do I fix my model and view so a person can add multiple skills and desired skills as sign up? (I am a rails beginner)

Comment: This is just my opinion but I would suggest leaving the User model to deal with authentication only and have a separate, linked `Profile` or `Person` model which can deal with holding skills etc. Otherwise your User model will get pretty cluttered pretty quickly.

Comment: I will also need to override the devise model to accomplish that right?

Comment: All you would need to do is add `has_one :person` to the devise model and `belongs_to :user` in your person model - or vice versa, depending on which one you want to have the id of the other.

Comment: So I did that and created the new model and used the has_one and has_many but when I refer to has_skills in my registration view I get an error : <div><%= f.label :has_skills %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :has_skills %></div>

Comment: field :has_skills, type => String but should it be an array. I need it to hold a user's skills like: fishing, cooking, coding, singing.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see the misunderstanding. Change has_skills back to skills and use  `has_one :skill` in the same way you'd use `embeds_many`. It's worth having a look at the mongoid docs for relations, it will help.

Answer (score 1):

`embeds_one` should be `embeds_many` if you want an array of skills.